# How get list of job types of simple job board plugin from code?

Tags: custom-post-types

My code to get a list of jobpost is this, but in this list don't show job types

```
 $active_jobs = get_posts( array(
                        'post_type'           => 'jobpost',
                        'post_status'         => array( 'publish', 'pending' ),
                        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                        'posts_per_page'      => 3,
                        'author'              => get_current_user_id()
                ) );
```

Comment: Is `jobpost` the correct slug for the post type?

Comment: yes, for the plugin simple-job-board

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
 $types = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'jobpost_job_type');
 var_dump($types);
```

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).